# How to use jquery or CSS to display the blue block after touching the yellow block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to ask you a question. I hope that when the yellow block is displayed, when the mouse hovers over the yellow block stone, the original blue block can be displayed again!

But I still can't achieve the effect after trying it for an afternoon. Would you like to ask everyone to help me see if there is a problem?
Thank you all for your help.

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
    var scrollH=$(document).scrollTop();
    if(scrollH > 60){
      $('.nav').addClass('up');
      $('.nav2').addClass('down');
    }else if(scrollH < 90){
       $('.nav').removeClass('up');
       $('.nav2').removeClass('down');
    }
})
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav2.down {
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
          animation: fadeIn 1s forwards;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after {
  content: ">";
  padding: 0px 8px;
}
.nav2 .breadcrumb .item::after:last-child {
  display: none;
}
.nav2 .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding: 3px;
  order: 3;
}
.nav2 .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav2 .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #1768ac;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav.up {
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
          animation: fadeout 1s forwards;
}
.nav .filter {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  order: 1;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.nav .filter .item {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.nav .category {
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
}
.nav .category .item {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.nav .search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
  order: 3;
}
.nav .search .fas {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px;
}
.nav .search .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e5d549;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">LOGO</div>


<div class="nav">
  <ul class="filter">
    <li class="item">HOT</li>
    <li class="item">NEW</li>
 </ul>
  <ul class="category">
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
    <li class="item">title</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="search">
    <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
    <input class="search_input" type="text" >
    <a  class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="nav2">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="item">index</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
    <li class="item">item</li>
  </ul>
   <div class="search">
      <label><i class="fas fa-search"></i></label>
      <input class="search_input" type="text" >
      <a  class="btn" href="javascript:;">BTN</a>
    </div>
</div>
  <div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.lorem100Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita vitae dolores accusantium voluptas facilis sint corporis, soluta esse nostrum culpa voluptatem temporibus est quidem adipisci laboriosam, mollitia suscipit nobis eveniet tenetur maxime! Explicabo quos, vitae officia commodi asperiores nobis dolorem mollitia minima reiciendis praesentium porro, eum soluta fuga. Eius dolorum debitis reprehenderit aut provident maiores iusto inventore molestiae tempora beatae fugit itaque hic, ad illo accusamus id quasi harum quis amet, incidunt nostrum nam. Expedita, nostrum. Enim, aperiam. Illum alias iure quas illo sint, deleniti optio porro velit deserunt! Quasi molestiae, nisi doloremque veniam earum veritatis libero ea assumenda est.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The yellow and blue blocks are not simply displayed and hidden, but the scroll bar changes cause the blue block to be invisible. When the mouse moves over the yellow block, do you want the scroll bar to return to the height when it was displayed in blue? ? Do the yellow block still need to be displayed at this time? Please elaborate.

Comment: HI @LouraQ
When the mouse touches the yellow block, the blue block will be displayed and return to the displayed height. There is nothing wrong with it!

But because I am only a beginner, I don’t know how to write~ Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the mouse touches the yellow block, the blue block will be displayed and return to the displayed height.

Just add the following jquery :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nav2").on("mouseover", function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
})
```

Here is the example code: https://jsfiddle.net/9e2s18a0/19/

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have been thinking about it for a long time but I never thought of it!
But don't you need to adjust the position of opacity and z-index of nav2?
Why only need to adjust window.scrollTo(0, 0);
to display the blue area? Still don't understand the principle?

Comment: @WEIA In fact, the changes in the blue and yellow blocks of your page are mainly determined by your scroll bar. The existing jquery statement you provide uses the height of the scroll bar to determine whether the two blocks are displayed or hidden. Therefore, I only need to change the height of the scroll bar can trigger your first jquery method at the same time.

Comment: It turned out to be so, it seems I was too stupid!
Originally, I was a business person who started self-learning programs and wanted to be a front-end engineer, but after I started self-learning programs for a while!
I find that I don't seem to be suitable for writing programs. Sometimes simple questions have to be thought for a long time.

Finally, thank you not only for telling me, but also for telling me the principle.